# Remove pdf file cache

Tags: android, pdf, caching, xamarin

I have an URL with which I open the pdf file. The address does not change, but the pdf file can change. When the pdf file changes notification comes to the user opens the file again at the same URL, but the old file is opened. When I delete the application cache and reload this file, everything is fine.
How can I remove this caching from creating URI or Intent or something else?

```
        public void OpenPdfByUrl(string url)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            {
                return;
            }

            url = url.Replace(" ", "%20");
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(url);
            var browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri);

            try
            {
                context.StartActivity(browserIntent);
            }
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Install pdf reader", ToastLength.Short);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Have you solved this. I have a same problem now

Answer (score 0):

```
static int clearCacheFolder(final File dir, final int numDays) {
    int deletedFiles = 0;
    if (dir!= null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        try {
            for (File child:dir.listFiles()) {

                //first delete subdirectories recursively
                if (child.isDirectory()) {
                    deletedFiles += clearCacheFolder(child, numDays);
                }

                //then delete the files and subdirectories in this dir
                //only empty directories can be deleted, so subdirs have been done first
                if (child.lastModified() < new Date().getTime() - numDays * DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS) {
                    if (child.delete()) {
                        deletedFiles++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, String.format("Failed to clean the cache, error %s", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }
    return deletedFiles;
}
```

/*
 * Delete the files older than numDays days from the application cache
 * 0 means all files.
 */

```
public static void clearCache(final Context context, final int numDays) {
    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Starting cache prune, deleting files older than %d days", numDays));
    int numDeletedFiles = clearCacheFolder(context.getCacheDir(), numDays);
    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Cache pruning completed, %d files deleted", numDeletedFiles));
}
```

Comment: What context should I send there. Context of the application?

Comment: I call ClearCache(Application.Context,0), but it always finds only one empty folder and does not delete anything, before uploading the file and after its uploading nothing is added. Maybe I sent the wrong context